# "snapshot" of nodes at time of transaction

Tags: neo4j

I have a scenario where I have a few products that are sold during an event. These products are configured once and can be used at any event. I currently have the following nodes/relationships:

```
event-[:HAS_CURRENT_INVENTORY]->inventory-[:OF_PRODUCT]->product
```

The inventory here is for a single product, so I have a number of these for each event. When a transaction occurs, I want to maintain a snapshot of inventory across all products that I sell at the event. I am currently thinking of doing it this way:

- Create a new transaction node
- Create new "inventory" nodes for all of the inventory items included in this transaction with new inventory count
- Link the new transaction node to all the "current" inventory nodes (not just the ones in the transaction, but all of them)
- Replace the "HAS_CURRENT_INVENTORY" relationship to the inventory nodes affected, and give them an "archived" relationship. Simultaneously, create "HAS_CURRENT_INVENTORY" links to the new inventory nodes.

Is there a more optimal way to implement this? It is important to have a snapshot of inventory levels across the event when a single transaction occurred, or at an arbitrary point in time. However, I am creating a tonne of stuff for each transaction at the event. Is there a better way to query the info?

Comment: I'm assuming that when you talk about transaction, you are talking about a sales transaction?

Comment: Yes, I meant a sales transaction.

Comment: I think this looks ok. Maybe you can even look at the thoughts in https://github.com/ccattuto/neo4j-dynagraph/wiki/Representing-time-dependent-graphs-in-Neo4j where a graph is essentially snapshotted, too.